# How To Remove "Roles" Option in Orchard User Registration Page

Tags: registration, orchardcms, profiles

I installed Profiles Module and then Extended Registration module. And I am collecting various information from users on the Orchard Registration page. However, the last part of that page asks users to identify their "Role" with check boxes for either Admin, Edit, Moderator, etc...

I don't want users to see this option at all when creating a profile.

Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try suppressing the shape by using placement.info? Use Shape Tracing to find out the name of the shape (it will even tell you the structure of the xml entry in placements.info you can use to control the shape).

Comment: I think you see the role part because you've signed with administrator. If you are anonymous you won't see that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the "extended registration" module but, if you edit the "User" content type, is there a part related to roles?

If so, you could remove this part from the "User" content type.

Hope this solves your problem.